# PHP вывести список файлов и папок в json

Tags: php

Генерирую список файлов и папок в json формате, файлик, который запускаю, находится в этой же папке, и автоматически попадает в этот список. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исключить php файлик из этого списка?

```
    function get_filelist_as_array($dir, $recursive = true, $basedir = '') {
    if ($dir == '') {return array();} else {$results = array(); $subresults = array();}
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {$dir = dirname($dir);}
    if ($basedir == '') {$basedir = realpath($dir).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;}

    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $key => $value){
        if ( ($value != '.') && ($value != '..') ) {
            $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                if ($recursive) {
                    $subdirresults = get_filelist_as_array($path,$recursive,$basedir);
                    $results = array_merge($results,$subdirresults);    
                }
            } else {$subresults[] = str_replace($basedir,'',$path); }
        }
    }
    if (count($subresults) > 0) {
        $results = array_merge($subresults,$results);
            foreach ($results as $key => $res){
                $hash = md5_file($res);
                $size = filesize($res);
                $a[] = array("fileName" => "$res", "fileHash" => "$hash", "fileLenth" => "$size"); 

            }
    }

   file_put_contents("update.json", json_encode(array('Update'=>$a)));
   return $results;
}
$dir = 'C:\wamp64\www\111';
return get_filelist_as_array($dir);
```

Comment: Можно также использовать basename(__FILE__) чтобы получить название исполняемого файла - это на тот случай если ваш скрипт в одном файле. (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте вот так:

```
if ( ($value != '.') && ($value != '..') && ($value != 'filename.ext') )
```

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло